# How to define a location regex matching block in nginx.conf

Tags: docker, nginx, nginx-config

I have a webapp with nginx (within a docker container: webserver_nginx_1) which I'm trying to configure.

The .html code structure:

- admin_view_groups.html expand layout.html (via jinja2)
- admin_view_groups.html, loads main.js via layout.html

I expect the following mapping, based on the "location ~ /V1" block in nginx.conf:
`/V1/js/mlj/main.js` -> `/usr/src/app/web/V1/js/mlj/main.js`

```
# the file exists within the container  
docker  exec  -it webserver_nginx_1 bash
root@90c800c4bd28:/# ls -l /usr/src/app/web/V1/js/mlj/main.js
-rwxrwxrwx 1 1000 1000 1709 Jan  9 06:49 /usr/src/app/web/V1/js/mlj/main.js
```

But the file is not loaded, and I see the following errors:

```
# In chrome devtools
GET https://localhost/admin_edit_group/V1/js/mlj/main.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
   
# In the log file for the nginx docker container I get a 404 error
# docker logs -f webserver_nginx_1
...
172.28.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2021:06:20:21 +0000] "GET /admin_edit_group/V1/js/mlj/main.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://localhost/admin_edit_group/2" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36" "-"
172.28.0.1 - - [10/Jan/2021:06:20:21 +0000] "GET /admin_edit_group/V1/js/mlj/main.js HTTP/2.0" 404 548 "https://localhost/admin_edit_group/2" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/75.0.3770.142 Safari/537.36" "-"
2021/01/10 06:20:21 [error] 7#7: *14 open() "/etc/nginx/htmlindex.php" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 172.28.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /admin_edit_group/V1/js/mlj/main.js HTTP/2.0", host: "localhost", referrer: "https://localhost/admin_edit_group/2"
```

the log for the "V1" location block:

- does not show any error
- shows the following debug messages

```
tail -f /var/log/nginx/V1-error.log
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 http script copy: "/usr/src/app/web/V1"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 http script var: "/V1/js/mlj/main.js"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 trying to use file: "/V1/js/mlj/main.js" "/usr/src/app/web/V1/V1/js/mlj/main.js"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 http script var: "/V1/js/mlj/main.js"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 trying to use dir: "/V1/js/mlj/main.js" "/usr/src/app/web/V1/V1/js/mlj/main.js"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 trying to use file: "/index.html" "/usr/src/app/web/V1/index.html"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 trying to use file: "index.php" "/usr/src/app/web/V1index.php"
2021/01/10 06:34:31 [debug] 9#9: *2 internal redirect: "index.php?"
```

---

It looks like within the location matching block:

- the string `V1/js/mlj/main.js` is matched
- the file `/usr/src/app/web/V1/js/mlj/main.js` is not found
- the dir `/usr/src/app/web/V1/js/mlj/main.js/` is not found
- the file `/index.html` is not found
- the file `index.php` is not found

**My question is:**
In nginx, within a location block:

- how can I match a substring e.g. `/V1` within a string e.g. `admin_edit_group/V1/js/mlj/main.js`  ? (when the regex pattern is in the middle of the string)
- when the regex pattern is matched in the middle of the string, why is the file not found?

---

Related code:

```
# the html files:
cat admin_view_groups.html
...
{% extends "layout.html" %}

# --------------------------------------------------------------

cat layout.html
...
<script type="module" src="V1/js/mlj/main.js"></script>

# --------------------------------------------------------------

# the location regex block in the nginx conf file
cat nginx.conf
...

    location ~ /V1 {
        error_log /var/log/nginx/V1-error.log info; 
        autoindex on;
        alias /usr/src/app/web/V1;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html index.php;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several problems with your `location` block.

- Using `alias` within a regular expression `location` requires captures to build the full path to the file (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias))
- Using `alias` and `try_files` within the same block can lead to strange side-effects (see [this document](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/97))
- You do not need both `/index.html` and `/index.php` at the end of the `try_files` statement. Choose which one is needed to use a `=404` code (see [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files))
- All URIs in Nginx begin with a leading `/` - use `/index.php` instead of `index.php'

---

To match any URI containing an embedded `/V1/`, you could use:

```
location ~ (/V1.*)$ {
    root /usr/src/app/web;
    try_files $1 =404;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Your first comment (requires captures to build the full path) is the part that I was missing.
By the way in [the link that you referred to](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) says: ```regular expression should contain captures and alias should refer to these captures...```. Where do you see the **full path** requirement?
I eventually solved the problem by using ```root``` instead of ```alias```

Comment: I inferred it from the example they give.